# Can I add roles to roles in ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 user concept?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

Within ArcGis Server 10.3.1 with LDAP Security, I have an existing role containing users, which I would now like to add to another role. For Example I have "Edit_Role_01" and  "Edit_role_02". I now want to add these 2 roles to a role called "Editors".

I can´t seem to see how I could add a role to a role. Is this not possible?

Comment: [How ArcGIS Server security works](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/how-arcgis-server-security-works.htm)

Comment: As far as I can see then, roles can´t be added to other roles.But if there are user groups made with Windows server, these can be added to a role. Right?

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the identity provider.

Comment: The internal provider does not permit groups in groups.  External providers could support ***anything*** but their configuration is off-topic for GIS SE.